# Unknown Error with Conversion [C]

Tags: c, char

For some reason when building my program, it says that I have this error:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
       strcpy(phrase[counter].word, ch);
```

I'm not really sure what the compiler means, I've tried changing `char ch` to `const char ch`, but that doesn't seem to fix the issue. If anyone could shed some light on this issue that would be great.

Here is the code you can refer to:

```
const char* clean_word(void);

void create_word(struct Word_setup phrase[], FILE *fp)
{
    char ch;

    fscanf(fp, "%s", &ch);
    strcpy(phrase[counter].word, ch);
    strcpy(phrase[counter].word, clean_word());
}

const char* clean_word()
{   
    int i;
    const char *ch = phrase[counter].word;

    ch = phrase[counter].word;

    for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        if (phrase[counter].word[i] == 39 || isalpha(phrase[counter].word[i])) //39 is the ASCII value for: '
            i = i; //Just to be there, no reason to it. I just want the program to do nothing if its a letter or '
        else
            phrase[counter].word[i] = '\0';
    }
    return ch;
}
```

Also in case you're wondering what this is for, I'm building a program that will scan a `*.txt` file and then print out the word with the highest number of appearances, as as well as the number of appearances.

**If** you've already read my old post, I decided to try writing it without re-allocating space every time the array gets filled, and I just set it to 200 max different types of words. I will change the program once I'm finished so that it reallocates space every time that the array fills up.

Comment: you're missing the pointer on char ch.

Comment: Repeating yourself with: `const char *ch = phrase[counter].word; ch = phrase[counter].word;` really doesn't help, though it doesn't do a huge amount of damage in this context (in others, such as memory allocation, it might be harmful).

Comment: regarding this line: 'for (i = 0; i < M; i++)'  I do not find 'M' either declared nor set anywhere in the code.  Does this posted code even compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe...

```
void create_word(struct Word_setup phrase[], FILE *fp)
{
    fscanf(fp, "%s", phrase[counter].word);
    clean_word();
}
```

Comment: wow, thats much smarter... I should have thought of that haha

Comment: @Nicolas Not only smarter, your code experiences buffer overflow in `scanf` – it reads a string into single-char location on stack.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here:

```
    char ch;

    fscanf(fp, "%s", &ch);
    strcpy(phrase[counter].word, ch);
```

The `strcpy()` function expects its second argument to be a *pointer* to the head of the source string, but `ch` is a `char`, not a `char *` or `const char *`.  As Keith Thompson explained, this is an error because integers  are not implicitly convertible to pointers in C (other than a constant expression with value 0).  Even if the compiler performed an implicit conversion anyway, the behavior would surely not be what you want.

Moreover, the `fscanf()` isn't going to do what you want, either, because even though argument `&ch` is the correct *type* for the format string it accompanies, it is a pointer to only a single character of storage, and the fscanf will *always* write outside its bounds if it successfully scans a string (because it must write a string terminator even for a one-character string).

@BLUEPIXY's approach is much better, supposing that `phrase[counter].word` is a `char` array, but even there you risk overrunning its bounds.  To protect yourself against that, specify a field width.  For instance, if `phrase[counter].word` is an array of 20 `char`s, then use this ...

```
    fscanf(fp, "%19s", phrase[counter].word);
```

... to ensure that `scanf()` does not write more than 20 chars (including a string terminator) to the array.

Comment: and `strcpy(phrase[counter].word, clean_word());` is UB.

Comment: "*I'm uncertain why this is an error, as all integer values are convertible to pointers in C*" -- Integer values (other than the special case of `0` which is a null pointer constant) are not *implicitly* convertible to pointers.